# How exactly does Power propagate through Power related Blocks?

Tags: fortresscraft-evolved

Consider this example setup:

[image: Screenshot of example]

How does the power propagate through those blocks? Die the extra 2 Blocks help powering the Turret? (Ignore the fact for now that one would be enough for a turret). I am asking because I had issues powering a Resin Ablater and Liquifier. Then I made a setup like this and it only started working once I have pointed Lasers down, like this:

[image: Screenshot of possible solution]

So I am wondering how this works and what the best solution is to power devices that are very power hungry and over a distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so from what I understand of Fortesscraft's power storage and laser emitters I believe that the second setup you have shown is actually detrimental to your plan of sending additional power as LETS's pull energy from every direction including the side that the laser is on. If you wish to send the power from 3 PSB's to 1 turrent or machine then it much wiser to have an air gap between each PSB and LET couple with 2 of the lasers feeding into one laser that then provides the main energy stream.

The FortressCraft Evolved fandom wiki has a much deeper explanation for how the lasers and storage units work.

Heres [the link](http://fortresscrafte.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Storage) to the page you will want to look at.

Basically in your first picture the turret would draw power from the PSB its directly connected to which would draw on the PSB above that and so on.

In your second picture laser emitters only send power in the direction you have the laser itself facing so yes it would only work once you had faced all the lasers in the correct direction for them to be able to actually send power to another suitable block.

And lastly its better to have an air-gap between a laser and storage couple if you are sending energy over a long distance. You can also chain LET's together if the distance is quite large obviously not right next to each other but enough blocks apart for you so save on resources.

EDIT: I wasn't happy with my explanation of how the PSBs pass and store power so I managed to find the original Steam post that I used when 1.9 was released.

Heres [the link to the Steam Community page](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=507800233)

To give an overview, PSBs can receive and send power out of each face on the block simultaneously. However they can only ever pass 20% of their energy and can only receive 20% of their total capacity. So you do actually have an exponential lose of power the more PSBs you stack together without an air-gap.

Hope this edit gives you whatever information I orginally miss interpreted or missed all together.